# Заполнение recyclerview информацией из БД на основе выбранного элемента

Tags: php, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-spinner

Всем привет!

Возникла абсолютно нелепая ситуация. Не строится рабочий алгоритм по получению массива данных из БД на основе выбранного элемента. Суть работы формы состоит в выборе конкретной команды и получения списка пилотов, состоящих в этой команде.

Дано: 
1. Android Studio
2. PHP
3. MySQL
4. Spinner. В выпадающий список я загружаю позиции из моей БД (mysql)
5. Recyclerview. Сюда загружается итоговый список из БД на основе выбора в спинере.

Как работает приложение в настоящий момент:
При открытии формы приложение получает от сервера выборку основных позиций из базы данных. Далее я отправляю данные о пользователе (кто конкретно) и его выбору в базу. Записываю в базу выбранное значение. Потом я снова обращаюсь к базе и прошу дать мне список пилотов, состоящих в выбранной пользователем команде. Именно в этом месте у меня возникает проблема. Т.к. данные о том, какой пользователь обращается к базе я отправляю в запросе, который не связан с последним действием, я не могу получить нужный мне список. Когда по второму запросу указываю конкретные данные в файле php (в процессе тестирования) конечно же всё работает.
товарищи, помогите, пожалуйста, связать два шага в один: отправку данных о том, какой пользователь работает с формой и какую команду он выбрал и получение итогового списка.

Прилагаю всё, что есть по данной проблеме. Очень хочу понять как это работает,  но силы на исходе.
СПАСИБО!

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
public class Teams extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String HttpURL = "https://amkcrace.ru/app/teams1.php";
  SharedPreferences settings;
  SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
  List < STeams > teamsList;
  RecyclerView recyclerView;
  HashMap < String, String > hashMap = new HashMap < > ();
  String finalResult, ITEM, email;
  HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
  ArrayList < String > listItems = new ArrayList < > ();
  ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;
  Spinner sp;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.teams_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.team_list, R.id.textViewLName, listItems);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    teamsList = new ArrayList < > ();

    settings = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERNCES_Login, 0);
    prefEditor = settings.edit();
    email = settings.getString("EMAIL", "");
    Toast.makeText(Teams.this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  }

  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    BackTask bt = new BackTask();
    bt.execute();
  }
  //заполняю спиннер
  private class BackTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {
    ArrayList < String > list;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      list = new ArrayList < > ();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
      InputStream is = null;
      String result = "";
      try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(HttpURL);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }


      try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          result += line;
        }
        is.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

      }

      try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

          list.add(jsonObject.getString("team"));
        }

      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      listItems.addAll(list);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener; {
      itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
          ITEM = item;
          replaceOldListWithNewList();
          ListFunction(ITEM, email);
         }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent) {}
      };

      sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);

    }
  }

  //сообщаю базе выбор пользователя
  public void ListFunction(final String item, final String email) {
    class ListFunctionClass extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Teams.this, "Минуточку...", null, true, true);

      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

        hashMap.put("item", params[0]);
        hashMap.put("email", params[1]);

        finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, "https://amkcrace.ru/app/test.php");
        loadSTeams();
        return finalResult;
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
        super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(Teams.this, httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }

    ListFunctionClass ListFunctionClass = new ListFunctionClass();
    ListFunctionClass.execute(item, email);
  }


  //заполнение итогового списка
  private void loadSTeams() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://amkcrace.ru/app/test.php",
      new Response.Listener < String > () {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

              JSONObject team = array.getJSONObject(i);

              teamsList.add(new STeams(

                team.getString("last_name"),
                team.getString("first_name")
              ));
            }
            TeamAdapter adapter = new TeamAdapter(Teams.this, teamsList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      },
      new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
      });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
  }

  //очистка списка для его повторного заполнения
  private void replaceOldListWithNewList() {

    teamsList.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

}
```

```js
package ru.amkc.amkc;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class TeamAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < TeamAdapter.TeamViewHolder > {


  private Context mCtx;
  private List < STeams > teamsList;

  public TeamAdapter(Context mCtx, List < STeams > teamsList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.teamsList = teamsList;
  }

  @Override
  public TeamViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_list, null);
    return new TeamViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(TeamViewHolder holder, int position) {
    STeams team = teamsList.get(position);

    holder.textViewLName.setText(team.getLName() + " " + team.getFName());
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return teamsList.size();
  }

  class TeamViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewLName;

    public TeamViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      textViewLName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLName);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
public class STeams {
    private String lname;
    private String fname;


    public STeams(String lname, String fname) {

        this.lname = lname;
        this.fname = fname;


    }

    public String getLName() {return lname;}

    public String getFName() {
        return fname;
    }


}
```

```html
//для спиннера
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';
 
 $teams=$con->query("SELECT id_team, team FROM team");
 while($row = $teams->fetch_assoc()){
    $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
}

$con->close();


?>
```

```js
//сообщаю базе выбор пользователя и выгружаю список

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

$item = $_POST['item']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];

$team=$con->query("SELECT registration.last_name, registration.first_name FROM registration WHERE  
registration.id_team=(SELECT team.id_team FROM team WHERE 
team.team='$item')");
 while($row = $team->fetch_assoc()){
    $list[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($list);


$Sqli_Query = "UPDATE registration SET app_team='$item' WHERE user_email='$email'";

if(mysqli_query($con,$Sqli_Query))
{
 echo 'Record Updated Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }

}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Вам нужно вывести информацию в лог что вы отправляетес андроида, на сервере php вывести информацию что получаете, и что возвращает запрос с БД, и уже после, что получает сам клиент на андроиде.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема состоит в том, что после отправки заявки на регистрацию, возвращается список зарегистрировавшихся пилотов без нового пользователя?
Если это так, то нужно сначала обновить запись в таблице, а потом уже запросить список.

Если код был верен, то его необходимо изменить как-то так:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

$item = $_POST['item']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];

$Sqli_Query = "UPDATE registration SET app_team='$item' WHERE user_email='$email'";

mysqli_query($con,$Sqli_Query);

$team=$con->query("SELECT registration.last_name, registration.first_name FROM registration WHERE  
registration.id_team=(SELECT team.id_team FROM team WHERE 
team.team='$item')");
 while($row = $team->fetch_assoc()){
    $list[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($list);

$con->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: 1. я не добавляю пользователя. я добавляю информацию в ячейку уже существующей строки. 2. json_encode() работает только тогда, когда он стоит первым запросом в файле. Это не могу объяснить. Код, представленный здесь полностью рабочий. Всё что нужно - связать 2 функции (добавление информации в базу и выгрузку информации на ее основе) в одну. Я не могу понять, как это сделать.

Comment: @TaramParam Подправил код в ответе. Попробуйте так.

Comment: я боюсь, что дело не в части php... Править надо код приложения. На данный момент я трижды обращаюсь к серверу. Именно по этой причине переменные, заполняемые во время отправки данных из приложения на сервер, обнуляются к тому моменту, когда я вытягиваю итоговую информацию из базы. Есть мысли как собрать в одну функцию две абсолютно противоположные по значению?)

Comment: @TaramParam Кажется понял. Три запроса делать не нужно. Нужно убрать строку `finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, "https://amkcrace.ru/app/test.php");` И передать переменную hashMap в private void loadSTeams(HashMap hashMap). Ну и, соответственно, в этой функции должен быть POST запрос, содержащий hashMap. Сейчас там GET, который PHP скрипт игнорирует, т.к. не выполняется условие `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')`